# Hash to open modal on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hash, modal-dialog

I have the following snippet which should check for the hash and if there is a hash open bootstrap modal. My modals markups are generated dynamically with handlebars. On hashchange event is working fine but on page load with hash modal do not open.

```
    //Render Handlebars
    var iniCycles = function() {

            var r = $.Deferred();
            var data = [];
            if ($('ul.cycle-slideshow').length) {
                $('ul.cycle-slideshow').map(function() {
                    var hash = $(this).data('id');
                    var source = $("#" + hash).html();
                    data.push( {'image': $(this).find('img').prop('src') });
                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    $('body').append(template(data));
                }).get();
            }
            return r;
    };

    var modalOpen = function (hashtag) {
         $(hashtag).modal('toggle');
         $(hashtag).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
         history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
            });
    };


$(document).ready(function () {

    //This part is working
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        var modal_hash = window.location.hash; 
        modalOpen(modal_hash);
    });

    //on page load check for the hash, if there is a hash call modalOpen. This one in function is empty is something to do with handlebars I think
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var modal_url = window.location.hash; 
        iniCycles().done( modalOpen(modal_url) );

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the hashtag value corresponds to an existing html element with the same ID? Do a console.log($(hashtag))

Comment: console.log($(hashtag)) shows on first click an empty object on the second click I have the modal object an modal opens

Comment: Does the value for hashtag change between the first time and the second time? Do a console.log(hashtag) this time. If they are the same then we know that the element does not exist yet.

Comment: As I said first is empty in both console.log and the second click confirms the right id

Comment: Ok so does that help with your problem? Now you know that your html is not correct to do the modal

Comment: inside handlebars html is valid I just been validating